# Windows server 2008 can't uninstall FTP

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, ftp

I'm trying to uninstall the old IIS6 FTP service on Windows Server 2008 so that I can install FTP 7.5. In server manager I clicked remove role services and uninstalled FTP and restarted.

The Web Platform Installer 2.0 RC says FTP Service is still installed but it appears uninstalled in server manager. When I try to install FTP7.5 it says that it is incompatible with FTP and that I need to uninstall that first.

Is there something else that I need to do to get rid of the old FTP service?

Here is a screen shot showing what is installed and the error I'm receiving:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled the IIS6 parts and then uninstalled them again and it seemed to do the trick. Love these days.

Answer (score 0):

If i remember correctly, you have to remove IIS6 management tools and compability modules.

Comment: I've pretty much removed everything and still get the error. Added a screenshot to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Probable Solution

In 
Server manager- 
Remove roles- 
clear Ftp Server from it
and unistall it